# how to search for a phrase using regular expressions?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

please help to fix the script.

```
import urllib
import re
import os
import pprint

import requests
import bs4

stringHtml = urllib.request.urlopen('http://forum.saransk.ru/user/2018-sergey-kalinin/').read().decode('utf-8')
#print(stringHtml)
stringPattern = 'url\suid"\shref="http://vkontakte.ru/id10550933"'
result = re.search(stringPattern, stringHtml)
if result:
    print(result.group())
else:
    print('no result')
```

the problem is that the script displays a "no result". compiled regular expression correctly. please help find an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use `bs4` imported?

If you want print `href` attribute of the `a` element with class `uid` and `url`, you can use [`select` method (which accept css selector)](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors).

```
import urllib.request

import bs4

stringHtml = urllib.request.urlopen('http://forum.saransk.ru/user/2018-sergey-kalinin/').read()#.decode('utf-8')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(stringHtml)
for a in soup.select('a.url.uid'):
    print(a.get('href'))

# If you want to check whether the a tag with `href="http://vkontakte..."` exist,
#   use following lines instead.
# (CSS Selector `a.url.uid[href="..."]` does not work with bs4.
#  bs4 supports most commonly-used CSS selectors, not all of them)
#print(any(a.get('href') == 'http://vkontakte.ru/id10550933'
#      for a in soup.select('a.url.uid')))
```

output:

```
http://vkontakte.ru/id10550933
```

Comment: I think he's trying to check if it exists, put yes, this is a better way than regex

Comment: @RyanO'Donnell, If that is what OP want, replacing last two line with `print(any(a.get('href') == 'http://vkontakte.ru/id10550933' for a in soup.select('a.url.uid')))` will do the job.

Comment: thanks, but I know how to use the module "beautifulSoup". Now I'm curious decision by regular expressions

Comment: @Sergey, The regular expression has some issues: 1. You are match `"`, but after the uid, `'` comes. There's `ref` attribute between `class` and `href` attributes.

Comment: @Sergey, Try `print(re.search(r"url\s+uid'.+?href='http://vkontakte.ru/id10550933'", stringHtml))`

Comment: falsetru? thank you! this is solution     w = re.search(r"url\s+uid'.+?href='(http://vkontakte.ru/id10550933)'", stringHtml)
    print(w.group(1))

Comment: @Sergey, Yes, if you want get only the value of the `href` attribute, you should use capturing group. BTW, why do you use regular expression. RE version is more fragile. For example, if `url uid` is changed to `uid url`, RE version will not work while bs4 version still work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you have an error in your regex. You are looking for the text:

> url uid" href://vkontakte.ru/id10550933"

Looks like whitespace error?

Answer (score 0):

The page source shows

```
<a class="url uid" rel="external me" href="http://vkontakte.ru/id10550933">http://vkontakte.ru/id10550933</a>
```

so what you want is something like

```
import bs4
import requests

url = 'http://forum.saransk.ru/user/2018-sergey-kalinin/'
html = requests.get(url).content
page = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html)
link = page.find("a", {"class": "url uid"})
print(link["href"])
```

which gives

```
http://vkontakte.ru/id10550933
```